# How do I disambiguate this call to a generic function with a function parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, ambiguous

I'm writing a parser class that expects to read a sequence of tokens in a specific order. Some productions in its grammar have non-terminals that are optional, so I was wanting to make a generic "maybe" function that could be passed the function responsible for parsing the non-terminal as a callback. Typically, the function would throw an error on failure, but since it is optional is some cases, the maybe function would suppress the error. However, Swift is providing the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context," and I can't figure out the correct set of casts and/or typings to disambiguate it.

Here is the minimal amount of code I was able to write to recreate the error:

```
public struct VariableDeclaration {
    public let identifier: Identifier
    public let type: String?
}

public struct Identifier { }

public class Parser {
    
    public func parseVariableDeclaration() throws -> VariableDeclaration {
        let identifier = try self.parseIdentifier()
        let type = self.maybe(self.parseType)
        return VariableDeclaration(identifier: identifier, type: type)
    }
    
    public func parseIdentifier() throws -> Identifier { return Identifier() }
    
    public func parseType() throws -> String { return "" }
    
    public func maybe<T>(_ callback: (Parser) -> () throws -> T) -> T? {
        do {
            return try callback(self)()
        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And here are some of my failed attempts at disambiguating the problematic line:

```
let type: String? self.maybe(self.parseType)
let type = self.maybe(self.parseType) as String?
let type = self.maybe<String>(self.parseType)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is not the generic parameters. Your first and second attempt would tell the compiler what type `T` should be.

The issue is the value you pass as `callback`, which has the following signature:

```swift
(Parser) -> () throws -> T
```

You are passing in `self.parseType` which has the following signature:

```swift
() throws -> String
```

What would work is using `Self.parseType` (notice the capital `S`) or `Parser.parseType` as value for `callback`.

Alternatively, you could define `maybe` like this:

```swift
public func maybe<T>(_ callback: (Parser) throws -> T) -> T? {
    do {
        return try callback(self)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```swift
let type = self.maybe { try $0.parseType() }
```

Comment: I was unable to get `Self.parseType` to compile (it refused to convert `Self` to `Parser` for whatever reason), but `Parser.parseType` worked successfully. The lambda suggestion also worked. Thank you for the thorough response.

Comment: @Jared Ah, that's because `Parser` is a (non-final) class. So `Self` in a subclass would not be (an exact) `Parser`...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is really what you want to do, but if you want to keep the signature of `maybe`, you need to pass a partial reference of the method like this:

```
        let type = self.maybe(Parser.parseType)
```